# Firebase Cloud Function (Javascript) Parsing Error When Firebase Deploy

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I have a Javascript Cloud Function as below, and when I do Firebase deploy, I'm getting parsing error. I'm complaining about line `const response = await admin.messaging().sendToDevice(tokens, payload);`

```
'use strict';

const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');

admin.initializeApp();
const db = admin.firestore();


exports.sendFollowerNotification = functions.database.ref('/orders/{order_id}')
    .onWrite(async (change, context) => {

      // get vars
      const order_id = context.params.order_id;
      console.log('order_id:', order_id);

      const uid = change.after.data().uid;
      console.log('uid:', uid);

     // get user and send notifications
     const docRef = db.collection('users').doc(uid);
     const getDoc = docRef.get()
       .then(doc => {
           const fcmToken = doc.data().fcmToken;
           console.log('fcmToken:', fcmToken);

             const payload = {
               notification: {
                 title: 'We have received your order!',
                 body: `Thank you, we have received order ${order_id}`
               }
             };

             const response = await admin.messaging().sendToDevice(tokens, payload);
             console.log('response:', response);

       });

    });
```

Error:

```
 35:37  error  Parsing error: Unexpected token admin

✖ 1 problem (1 error, 0 warnings)

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! functions@ lint: `eslint .`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the functions@ lint script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using `await` without declaring the callback function as `async`. That's why you are getting a parsing error since `await` in of itself is irrelevant without having the parent function declared asynchronous. Try writing `docRef.get()` like such:

```
const getDoc = docRef.get()
       .then(async doc => {
           const fcmToken = doc.data().fcmToken;
           console.log('fcmToken:', fcmToken);

             const payload = {
               notification: {
                 title: 'We have received your order!',
                 body: `Thank you, we have received order ${order_id}`
               }
             };

             const response = await admin.messaging().sendToDevice(tokens, payload);
             console.log('response:', response);

       });
```

The only difference here is that I added `async` before the callback inside the `.then()`